# Altair transfrom_density

Tags: python, altair

I am trying to replicate this graph in Altair but for some reason is don't get any information on my chart, I can only see an empty chart.

[image]

[link to data](https://byuistats.github.io/CSE250-Course/skill_builders/ml_sklearn/machine_learning.csv)

My attempt:

```py
alt.Chart(data).transform_density('age', as_=['age', 'density'],
).mark_area(color='survived').encode(
    x="age",
    y='density:Q',
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`color` needs to be specified as an encoding when grouping by a variable, not as a mark parameter. In this case you also need to group the density calculation as in https://altair-viz.github.io/gallery/density_stack.html

```py
alt.Chart(data).transform_density(
    'age',
    as_=['age', 'density'],
    groupby=['survived']
).mark_area().encode(
    x="age",
    y='density:Q',
    color='survived:N'
)
```

[image]

Comment: I used your same code but I still get an empty graph, Maybe it is something wrong with my VS code?

Comment: @LeonardoUrbiola It is possible that's the cause. Does it work in jupyterlab?